# Evaluating a expression in quotes failing in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

```
*** Variables ***

${text1}      Jack's mother said "Hello" to me 
${text2}      Jack's mother said "Hello" to me

*** Test Cases ***
    ${result}=    Set Variable If    '${text1}' in '${text2}'    ${TRUE}    ${FALSE}
```

Above code is giving error as Evaluating expression failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Single quote is causing this issue, but I dont want to change variable value and evaluate them as they are. Replacing with double quotes is also not working and giving same error.

Can some one suggest how to evaluate this?

Comment: Without using ' is also giving same error

Comment: @Hunter: that is bad advice and won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use robot variables in expressions by removing the curly braces from the variable name.

```
${result}=    Set Variable If    $text1 in $text2    ${TRUE}    ${FALSE}
```

This is covered in the BuiltIn Library documentation under a section called [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use triple quotes in order to escape the string properly. This code runs fine

```
   *** Variables ***
    ${text1}      Jack's mother said "Hello" to me
    ${text2}      Jack's mother said "Hello" to me
    
    *** Test Cases ***
    Test
        ${result}=    Set Variable If    '''${text1}''' in '''${text2}'''    ${TRUE}    ${FALSE}
```

For more information have a look [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40045/escape-character-issue-in-run-keyword-if-in-robot-framework)